# If $p_n\to p$ and $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{|p_{n+1}-p|}{|p_n-p|^\alpha}=0$, what can be said of the order of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods, asymptotics

Let $\{p_n\}$ be  a sequence that converges to $p.$ If $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha }}=0$$ What can be said about the **order of convergence**?

**My attempt**
By the definition of limit,

If $\epsilon=1$, we can find a natural number $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0.$
$$|\frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha }}-0|<1$$

$$\implies \frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha }}<1$$

$$\implies\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|<\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha }$$
I don't know How to proceed. If the limit would be nonzero, I could say $\alpha$ is the order of convergence by the definition. Here I am helpless.

Useful definition
[here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BhuM.png)

> Definition. Let $\left\{p_{n}\right\}$ be a sequence that converges to a number $p .$ Let $e_{n}=$ $p_{n}-p$ for $n \geq 0 .$ If there exist positive constants $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ such that
> $$
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha}}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|e_{n+1}\right|}{\left|e_{n}\right|^{\alpha}}=\lambda
> .$$
> then $\left\{p_{n}\right\}$ is said to converge to $p$ of *order $\alpha$ with asymptotic error constant* $\lambda$.

Comment: @AlannRosas But in the Textbook of Brian Bradie introductions to numerical analysis, says asymptotic error constant have to be non zero.

Answer (score 5):

What you can conclude is that the order of convergence is not smaller than $\alpha$. Suppose the order, which I shall call $\beta$, is actually smaller than $\alpha$. The definition entails
$$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\beta}}>0.$$

As $\beta < \alpha$, we can write

$$ \frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\beta}} = \left(\frac{\left|p_{n+1}-p\right|}{\left|p_{n}-p\right|^{\alpha}}\right)\times |p_n-p|^{\alpha-\beta}$$
which is the product of two null sequences, whose limit must be in fact zero.

It is similarly easy to show that the order could be larger than $\alpha$. But the order could also not be larger: consider $$p_n = \frac{\log n}{n^\alpha }.$$